# ConcurrentHashMap contains values, but size() method returns 0

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

Experiencing weird behavior of `ConcurrentHashMap`: at first the map gets modified concurrently by several threads using compare-and-set operations like `putIfAbsent()` and `remove()`. After some time (tens of seconds or even a minute) another thread checks if the map is empty or not using two methods:

1. calling `myMap.isEmpty()` method
2. trying to see if there are any entries in iterator: `myMap.entrySet().iterator().hasNext()`

Surprisingly these two methods give different results. `isEmpty()` returns `true` and `iterator.hasNext()` returns `true` right after that. The calls are performed without any pause in between and no write operations are performed on the map at this time.

Please note, that according to logs there are no situations when `isEmpty()` returns `false` and `iterator.hasNext()` returns `false` at the same time. So it is always `isEmpty()` method not 'seeing' any entries in the map.

Wonder if this is expected behavior of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Documentation states that:

> Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods including size, isEmpty, and containsValue are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads. Otherwise the results of these methods reflect transient states that may be adequate for monitoring or estimation purposes, but not for program control.

That gives the idea that methods like `size()` and `isEmpty()` are expected to return values consistent with actual contents of the map when there are no ongoing write operations.

Comment: What are you using as key in the map?

Comment: @teemu-ilmonen I'm using immutable objects as keys. They have single `final long` field and `equals()` and `hashCode()` are auto-generated by IntelliJ Idea. So I'm pretty sure that keys are fine.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap.getEntrySet()` tells you that the iterator you obtain from the set is *weakly consistent*.

Javadoc for the `java.util.concurrent` package explains what "weakly consistent" means:

> ... their Iterators and Spliterators provide weakly consistent rather than fast-fail traversal:
>
> - they may proceed concurrently with other operations
> - they will never throw ConcurrentModificationException
> - they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

That last bullet is the important one.  It tells you that the iterator is a view of what was in the map at the moment when the iterator was created.  The contents of the iterator won't change if you subsequently change the contents of the map.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no modifications of the map are performed after creation of an iterator, so that is not the case.

Comment: @OlegMozzhechkov, I have to take your word for that because you have not shown us any code.  But you say that your program is multi-threaded, so what makes you _certain_ that no modifications happen?

Comment: Good point! To give Unfortunately there is too much code to just put it here, but what I have is a ConcurrentHashMap that is being modified by multiple threads and single monitor thread that checks whether the map is empty or not. Here is the code for emptiness check:  
    boolean notEmpty = waitingRequests.entrySet().iterator().hasNext();  
    LOGGER.debug("hasPullRequests? waitingRequest={} notEmpty?{}: {}", waitingRequests.size(), notEmpty, this);

Comment: What I see in logs is that there are two log entries one in a minute after another with size=0, notEmpty=true and exactly the same object in the map. And I am 100% sure that objects get put to the map only once after creation. There is simply no code to put them there back after removal.

Comment: @OlegMozzhechkov, Re, "Unfortunately there is too much code to just put it here."  So create an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/):  Cut your code down to a small example that does not behave the way you think it should behave.  There's a good chance that you will find the cause of your misunderstanding in the process of the SSCCE.  If not, you can post it here, and somebody will likely be able to help you.